# How to improve PaddleOCR performance, it is sometimes not able to detect space in between words

Tags: ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I am working on data extraction from daily use items using paddleOCR, it is working fine in most of the cases but somethime it mixes two or more words as a single word it does not take space into action
is there a better way to solve this

thanks in advance!!!

have tried running on version 2.6.1.3 and extracting english text form daily household things like price, batch no. etc

Answer (score 0):

you should finetune Paddle text recognition model with your new dataset. for more information check [this link](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.6/doc/doc_en/finetune_en.md)  this is about how to finetune paddle models.

If you want to read more about text recognition finetuning check [here](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.6/doc/doc_en/recognition_en.md#Dataset_download)